# Issue with stringstream data getting corrupt.

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have an issue using stringstreams

When I run this code the first printf is fine but at some point it gets contaminated and prints out a shorter string.

```
string CJpsURI::getURIwithSipIpPort()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "sip:" << m_ipAddr << ":" << m_portAddr;
    string out = ss.str();
}

main() {

    CJpsURI localIp();
    localIp.setIpPort("192.168.88.1", 5060);

    char *s = localIp.getURIwithSipIpPort().c_str();

    printf("This is the sip port: %s", s);  // this may be ok  -- sip:192.168.88.1:5060
    // do some stuff
    printf("This is the sip port: %s", s);  // wrong; -- sip:192.168.8/030/004

}
```

It almost appears that the *s is pointing to the out string on the stack which gets destroyed.  But that should not be happening since I am returning out and not a reference to out.

But this seems to work.

```
string CJpsURI::getURIwithSipIpPort()
{
    string out = (boost::format("sip:%1%:%2%") % m_ipAddr % m_portAddr).str();
    return out;
}

main() {

    CJpsURI localIp();
    localIp.setIpPort("192.168.1.1", 5060);

    char *s = localIp.getURIwithSipIpPort().c_str();

    printf("This is the sip port: %s", s);  // this may be ok
    // do some stuff
    printf("This is the sip port: %s", s);  // this will be ok too;

}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Your first function does not return anything.

Comment: Which is undefined behavior (in reference to @Galik's comment.)

Comment: Even if you *do* return `out`, `s` is the result of calling `c_str()` on a temporary `string`, so dereferencing it is undefined. In both cases. It's just bad luck that it "works".

Comment: So many comments in my code trying various thing that I did a bad copy and paste. My original code had "return out" as my last statement.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

1. As [remyabel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3920237/remyabel) and [Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik) pointed out: Your function does not return. So I would Concur with [Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik) that you need to adapt your function to:

`string CJpsURI::getURIwithSipIpPort()`
`{`
 `stringstream ss;`
 `ss << "sip:" << m_ipAddr << ":" << m_portAddr;`
 `return ss.str();`
`}`

2. A `char*` points to an array of `char`s. Here you want the array found inside the string returned by `getURIwithSipIpPort`. **But that memory will be released as soon as this line ends!** There is nothing hanging on to it. So what you really need to do is:

   string s{localIp.getURIwithSipIpPort()};

Comment: So many comments in my code trying various thing that I did a bad copy and paste. My original code had "return out" as my last statement.

Comment: @user846566 If setting the code up as explained in one of our answers solved your problem I'd encourage you to accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard says:

> § 6.7/2 *[..]* Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a
>   return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a
>   value-returning function.

The second problematic statement is:

```
char *s = localIp.getURIwithSipIpPort().c_str();
```

First, the conversion from `const char*` to `char*` is deprecated. Use `const char*`. Second, **don't do this** in the first place. If you want to prolong the lifetime of a temporary, use a const reference.

```
const std::string& s = localIp.getURIwithSipIpPort().c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your first function does not return anything:**

```
string CJpsURI::getURIwithSipIpPort()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "sip:" << m_ipAddr << ":" << m_portAddr;
    string out = ss.str(); // This does not get returned!
}
```

**Try this:**

```
string CJpsURI::getURIwithSipIpPort()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "sip:" << m_ipAddr << ":" << m_portAddr;
    return ss.str(); // Now it returns something!
}
```

Comment: So many comments in my code trying various thing that I did a bad copy and paste.  My original code had "return out" as my last statement.